# Can i create get directions by using OpenStreetMap data on the Google Maps? How?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, openstreetmap

I am starting to create a site that finds users location and if he want to go to another place, he will have to click one balloon to get directions into that place. I am doing everything on google maps, but i want to use get direction data from openstreetmaps. How can i get data from OpenStreetMaps into Google Maps to draw the route? Please help me for this issue.
Best regards

Comment: Directions that are not consistent with the base map tiles could be confusing (they might not match the roads shown).

Answer (score 0):

Choose a [OSM routing service](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing) that offers GPX export and display the result on top of a Google Map. Although I don't understand why anybody should want that because it may create confusing results as already pointed out by user geocodezip.